# what's Cast to ObjectId failed for value "ascendPrice" at path "_id" for model "Product"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
sortByAscend (req, res) {
    Product.find({}).aggregate([
        {$sort: {price: 1}}
    ])
    .then(ascend => {
        console.log("Displaying ascended price")
        res.status(201).json({
            ascend
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({
            message: "Internal server error"
        })
    })
}
```

I was sending a request `GET` to show the output of the sorted ascended price.

The error is

> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "ascendPrice" at path
> "_id" for model "Product"

I don't understand what the error is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory. Path `_id` has to be in a specific format and string `ascendPrice` doesn't it.

Mongo `_id` has to be an [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) which is compouned (as docs explain) by:

- a 4-byte timestamp value, representing the ObjectId’s creation, measured in seconds since the Unix epoch
- a 5-byte random value
- a 3-byte incrementing counter, initialized to a random value

So the value you use has to match this and your number doesn't.

So the problem is in your collection exists (at least) one document which `_id` is`ascendPrice` and it doesn't follow the pattern and can't be cast to `ObjectId`.