# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "images" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a peculiar issue mongoose, I have dug around topics relating to my issue and I found on interesting response on another issue like mine [what's Cast to ObjectId failed for value "ascendPrice" at path "_id" for model "Product"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805928/whats-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-ascendprice-at-path-id-for-model). So what the response was is that at least one document has an irregular objectId field and that I say is unlikely. My issue is I have a specific route to upload to cloudinary. I have no issues with querying data from mongodb or interacting with the database with put or delete request. I am just hooking up to cloudinary and uploading data

```
const addImage = asyncHandler(async (requestObject, responseObject) => {
  const uploader = (path) => uploadToCloudinay(path, "images");
  const urls = [];
  const files = requestObject.files;
  for (const file of files) {
    const { path } = file;
    const newpath = await uploader(path);
    urls.push(newpath);
    fs.unlinkSync(path);
  }
  const images = urls.map((file) => file.url);
  if (images.length === 0)
    responseObject
      .status(417)
      .json({ message: "Unable to complete image upload please try again" });
  responseObject.status(200).json(images);
});
```

This is the redux slice handling the request and then passing it to the route

```
export const uploadImages = createAsyncThunk(
  "product/upload_images",
  async (value, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const formdata = new FormData();
      value.images.forEach((image) => formdata.append("images", image));
      value = { ...value, formdata };
      return await uploadFiles(value);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);
```

Then the request goes to the route handler

```
export const uploadFiles = async ({ token, formdata }) => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    `/api/products/stock/item/images`,
    formdata,
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      withCredentials: true,
    }
  );
  return response.data;
};
```

So i don't know how the error is arriving from this this lines of code. Please help point me in the right direction. There are no issue in postman when I test the route. Its fine there so I cant tell why.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first I made a silly mistake I just can't bring my self to comprehend. I sent the wrong request to the route, post instead of get. So I have rectified that. I spoke to some guys in IRC and that is where every programmer should be he said

`redneck_dysguys: im not sure what your use case is, but you're overcomplicating things for yourself. just use their React SDK or Upload widget or roll out your own control and just call their APIs and be done with it`

After I replied I noticed the disaffection for mongodb in the community when someone said I should stay away from it.

`silly, Don't use MongoDB - it has many issues, and is essentially never the right solution to your problem. Here's a list of issues: http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2015/07/19/why-you-should-never-ever-ever-use-mongodb/ and a more technical article at http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/`

The solution got is https://cloudinary.com/documentation/react_image_and_video_upload and he went on to advise how to approach it.
`i used neither. their widget is ugly and i didn't want another dependency/module for my use case. you can also just create a file input, let the user select images and send a POST request to their API at "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/upload" with your form-data. in case of successful upload, you will get a response with all the metadata including the upload url. this is what you store in your database`